# error in calculating beta in second order point wise mutual information

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, nlp

[image]

I followed this rule but my result  didn't meet the result in the paper !

while n=9 , segma= 0.7 ,f(W1)=11

the result in the paper for beta1= 6 and my result= 1.67 
what's the wrong with this ?

who know this algorithm,what's beta here refers to ?

Comment: please post a reference or link to the paper and also a link to your code so that people can help to understand what is the problem.

Comment: http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fijitcs.com%2Fvolume%25209_No_3%2Fp-rajkumar.pdf&ei=G8aeVMj7JYvvaNPYgbgH&usg=AFQjCNEoHtHtn9V4i1tMiFVzlwFRYc5zxQ&sig2=6x_5bO4gW5R2exB1LuLN5g&bvm=bv.82001339,d.d2s

Comment: my problem here is in mathematical and who know about this algorithm can help me in what's beta here refer to ?

Comment: Your question much better fits to http://cs.stackexchange.com. Or possibly to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/. But not on StackOverflow as it's not a specific programming question (in the sense of implementation).

Comment: Or perhaps http://statistics.stackexchange.com as the [tag:statistics] tag suggests by itself. [you're welcome ;)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper you posted gets the algorithm slightly wrong, so you shouldn't rely upon it. Try following along with the example in this paper instead:

http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~mdislam/publications/LREC_06_242.pdf

Comment: i had this paper and same problem with me, i can't find exactly what's beta refers to ? and trying to get the result but i can't get the same result in the paper although i followed the rule well

Comment: log in the paper refers to natural log. So to get the same result as in the paper, go:

beta1 = (ln(ft(W1)))^2 * (log2(n))/delta
= (ln(frequency of "car"))^2 * (log2(43))/0.7
= (ln(6))^2 * (log2(43))/0.7
= 24.88

Comment: thanks i tried it now and got the result, but what about the example in the post ? what's the result should be ?

Comment: As for what beta1 refers to -- it's just a variable, which is calculated using the formula you just mentioned. In the walk through example, that formula is used to compute a value of beta1. Then in the last step of the walkthrough example, that value is used to compute the final similarity.

Comment: The paper you linked seems to have an error. The result should be beta1 = (ln(11))^2 * (log2(9))/0.7 = 26.04.

Comment: ok i get it thanks, can you try the example in the post and tell me the result ? i got 25.8 is it right